# How to read from stdin with fgets()?

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I've written the following code to read a line from a terminal window, the problem is the code gets stuck in an infinite loop. The line/sentence  is of undefined length, therefore I plan to read it in parts into the buffer, then concatenate it to another string which can be extended via `realloc` accordingly. Please can somebody spot my mistake or suggest a better way of achieving this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 10

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    printf("Enter a message: \n");
    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems pretty ok, when do you want the loop to end ? As it is now, you can end it by hitting ctrl+d on *nix or ctrl+z on windows.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code - when you say "stuck in a infinite loop", what do you mean exactly ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

here a concatenation solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFERSIZE 10

int main() {
  char *text = calloc(1,1), buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
  printf("Enter a message: \n");
  while( fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) ) /* break with ^D or ^Z */
  {
    text = realloc( text, strlen(text)+1+strlen(buffer) );
    if( !text ) ... /* error handling */
    strcat( text, buffer ); /* note a '\n' is appended here everytime */
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
  }
  printf("\ntext:\n%s",text);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the `+1` on this line: `text = realloc( text, strlen(text)+1+strlen(buffer) );`  ?

Comment: @johngonidelis a string is stored as a series of the ascii value of the characters, with a single character at the end with the binary value '0'. strlen() only counts the actual letters, but when you lay out space for your own string, you need to include another single space for the null byte. This line has the amount of characters already in text, plus the amount of characters in the buffer, plus room for a single null byte to signify the end of the string.

Answer (score 7):

You have a wrong idea of what fgets returns. Take a look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

It returns null when it finds an EOF character. Try running the program above and pressing CTRL+D (or whatever combination is your EOF character), and the loop will exit succesfully.

How do you want to detect the end of the input? Newline? Dot (you said sentence xD)?

Comment: the end of the input should be a newline

Comment: Scan your buffer for newlines, then :)

Answer (score 4):

Exits the loop if the line is empty(Improving code).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// The value BUFFERSIZE can be changed to customer's taste . Changes the
// size of the base array (string buffer )    
#define BUFFERSIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    char cChar;
    printf("Enter a message: \n");
    while(*(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)) != '\n')
    {
        // For concatenation
        // fgets reads and adds '\n' in the string , replace '\n' by '\0' to 
        // remove the line break .
/*      if(buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n')
            buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0'; */
        printf("%s", buffer);
        // Corrects the error mentioned by Alain BECKER.       
        // Checks if the string buffer is full to check and prevent the 
        // next character read by fgets is '\n' .
        if(strlen(buffer) == (BUFFERSIZE - 1) && (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] != '\n'))
        {
            // Prevents end of the line '\n' to be read in the first 
            // character (Loop Exit) in the next loop. Reads
            // the next char in stdin buffer , if '\n' is read and removed, if
            // different is returned to stdin 
            cChar = fgetc(stdin);
            if(cChar != '\n')
                ungetc(cChar, stdin);
            // To print correctly if '\n' is removed.
            else
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Exit when Enter is pressed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 16

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    printf("Enter a message: \n");
    while(true)
    {
        assert(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin) != NULL);
        // Verifies that the previous character to the last character in the
        // buffer array is '\n' (The last character is '\0') if the
        // character is '\n' leaves loop.
        if(buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n')
        {
            // fgets reads and adds '\n' in the string, replace '\n' by '\0' to 
            // remove the line break .
            buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
            printf("%s", buffer);
            break;
        }
        printf("%s", buffer);   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Concatenation and dinamic allocation(linked list) to a single string.

```
/* Autor : Tiago Portela
   Email : sapitando@gmail.com
   Sobre : Compilado com TDM-GCC 5.10 64-bit e LCC-Win32 64-bit;
   Obs : Apenas tentando aprender algoritimos, sozinho, por hobby. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 8

typedef struct _Node {
    char *lpBuffer;
    struct _Node *LpProxNode;
} Node_t, *LpNode_t;

int main(void)
{
    char acBuffer[BUFFERSIZE] = {0};
    LpNode_t lpNode = (LpNode_t)malloc(sizeof(Node_t));
    assert(lpNode!=NULL);
    LpNode_t lpHeadNode = lpNode;
    char* lpBuffer = (char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));
    assert(lpBuffer!=NULL);
    char cChar;


    printf("Enter a message: \n");
    // Exit when Enter is pressed
/*  while(true)
    {
        assert(fgets(acBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)!=NULL);
        lpNode->lpBuffer = (char*)malloc((strlen(acBuffer) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        assert(lpNode->lpBuffer!=NULL);
        strcpy(lpNode->lpBuffer, acBuffer);
        if(lpNode->lpBuffer[strlen(acBuffer) - 1] == '\n')
        {
            lpNode->lpBuffer[strlen(acBuffer) - 1] = '\0';
            lpNode->LpProxNode = NULL;
            break;
        }
        lpNode->LpProxNode = (LpNode_t)malloc(sizeof(Node_t));
        lpNode = lpNode->LpProxNode;
        assert(lpNode!=NULL);
    }*/

    // Exits the loop if the line is empty(Improving code).
    while(true)
    {
        assert(fgets(acBuffer, BUFFERSIZE, stdin)!=NULL);
        lpNode->lpBuffer = (char*)malloc((strlen(acBuffer) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        assert(lpNode->lpBuffer!=NULL);
        strcpy(lpNode->lpBuffer, acBuffer);
        if(acBuffer[strlen(acBuffer) - 1] == '\n')
            lpNode->lpBuffer[strlen(acBuffer) - 1] = '\0';
        if(strlen(acBuffer) == (BUFFERSIZE - 1) && (acBuffer[strlen(acBuffer) - 1] != '\n'))
        {
            cChar = fgetc(stdin);
            if(cChar != '\n')
                ungetc(cChar, stdin);
        }
        if(acBuffer[0] == '\n')
        {
            lpNode->LpProxNode = NULL;
            break;
        }
        lpNode->LpProxNode = (LpNode_t)malloc(sizeof(Node_t));
        lpNode = lpNode->LpProxNode;
        assert(lpNode!=NULL);
    }


    printf("\nPseudo String :\n");
    lpNode = lpHeadNode;
    while(lpNode != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", lpNode->lpBuffer);
        lpNode = lpNode->LpProxNode;
    }


    printf("\n\nMemory blocks:\n");
    lpNode = lpHeadNode;
    while(lpNode != NULL)
    {
        printf("Block \"%7s\" size = %lu\n", lpNode->lpBuffer, (long unsigned)(strlen(lpNode->lpBuffer) + 1));
        lpNode = lpNode->LpProxNode;
    }


    printf("\nConcatenated string:\n");
    lpNode = lpHeadNode;
    while(lpNode != NULL)
    {
        lpBuffer = (char*)realloc(lpBuffer, (strlen(lpBuffer) + strlen(lpNode->lpBuffer)) + 1);
        strcat(lpBuffer, lpNode->lpBuffer);
        lpNode = lpNode->LpProxNode;
    }
    printf("%s", lpBuffer);
    printf("\n\n");

    // Deallocate memory
    lpNode = lpHeadNode;
    while(lpNode != NULL)
    {
        lpHeadNode = lpNode->LpProxNode;
        free(lpNode->lpBuffer);
        free(lpNode);
        lpNode = lpHeadNode;
    }
    lpBuffer = (char*)realloc(lpBuffer, 0);
    lpBuffer = NULL;
    if((lpNode == NULL) && (lpBuffer == NULL))
    {

        printf("Deallocate memory = %s", (char*)lpNode);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Am I wrong, or the loop is only exited if the empty line comes just after a BUFFERSIZE boundary?

Comment: @Alain BECKER I improved the code ( I guess ) , really out of the loop in this event , but now leaves only if the line is empty ( Pressing Enter without typing anything ) , I tested with TDM- GCC and LCC .

Comment: There is really not much point in (a) posting a wall of code (b) with no explanation to (c) a 6 year old question that (d) already has good answers.

Comment: @ Paul R If you run the code you will see that is self explanatory, and no response is satisfactory (exit loop with Ctrl + Z ) or something , and I am newbie at it , I used this question as a way to practice.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you only want to read a single line, then use `LINE_MAX`, which is defined in `<limits.h>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
...
char line[LINE_MAX];
...
if (fgets(line, LINE_MAX, stdin) != NULL) {
...
}
...
```

Comment: LINE_MAX is NOT C89 or C99, its only compiler specific

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate the input, then replace `printf("%s\n", buffer);` with `strcat(big_buffer, buffer);`. Also create and initialize the big buffer at the beginning: `char *big_buffer = new char[BIG_BUFFERSIZE];` `big_buffer[0] = '\0';`. You should also prevent a buffer overrun by verifying the current buffer length plus the new buffer length does not exceed the limit: `if ((strlen(big_buffer) + strlen(buffer)) < BIG_BUFFERSIZE)`. The modified program would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 10
#define BIG_BUFFERSIZE 1024

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    char *big_buffer = new char[BIG_BUFFERSIZE];
    big_buffer[0] = '\0';
    printf("Enter a message: \n");
    while(fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if ((strlen(big_buffer) + strlen(buffer)) < BIG_BUFFERSIZE)
        {
            strcat(big_buffer, buffer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new` is C++ but the question is about C

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of string that is read into the buffer each time, and use that to break out of the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 10

int main()
{
        char buffer[LEN];
        char *str = calloc(LEN,sizeof(char));
        short flag = 0;
        while(!flag && fgets(buffer, LEN, stdin))       
        {
                str = realloc(str, strlen(str)+strlen(buffer)+1);
                if(!str) exit(1);
                if(strlen(buffer) != LEN-1)
                        flag = 1;
                strcat(str,buffer);
        }
        printf("%s",str);
        return 0;
}
```