# Scanf won't continue after I seized an input text

Tags: c, arrays

so, I am basically building an array of students with their evaluation.

I made a basic struct :

```
struct Eleve{
    char Nom[100];
    int Note;
};

struct Eleve *array;
```

Then asking for how many children I want to input into my array, then loop and asking information for each child. But, when I enter an input into `scanf("%s\n", array[i].Nom);` the code stop.

```
    int nbEleves;
    float total = 0;
    printf("Nombre?!\n");
    scanf("%d", &nbEleves);

    array = malloc(nbEleves * sizeof(struct Eleve));
    int i = 0;
    while (i < nbEleves) {
        printf("Nom? ");
        scanf("%s\n", array[i].Nom);
        printf("La note? ");
        scanf("%d\n", &array[i].Note);
        total = total + array[i].Note;
        i++;
    }
```

It doesn't even go on the next `printf`. I don't understand why, because I don't get any build error or execution errors on this line. Eventually I would have looked at the format if by any chance I'd get an error there, but nothing. No errors, just not getting to the next step of the program.

I think my `scanf` looks right, and I've got no warnings on it. So, what can prevent the code to go further?

The data I entered in Nom is `test`.

Comment: "*I think my scanf looks right*" -- `%s` in `scanf()` is never *right*, it's always a *buffer overflow*. It **needs a field width**. And `\n` is just another whitespace character, which are not distiguished by `scanf()`, so you could as well put a simple space instead.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I did declared this way `
struct Eleve *array;` and entered 'test' as nom. You are right, I forgot to specify this.

Comment: The problem *could* be that it's actually advancing to the next `printf()` and you just don't see the text because the output buffer isn't flushed. Then, the `scanf("%d")` is waiting for more input.

Comment: Interactive input with `scanf()` is in general a bad idea and has **many** pitfalls. Read for example [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq). I also wrote a document on the subject: [A beginners' guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: @ArpitSvt [No, you don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/335858). (C++ is a different story).

Comment: Try adding a call to ` fflush(stdout)` after both `printf` calls in the loop, and see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: @FelixPalmen good read (not finished yet). Indeed, removing the \n solved the problem, but I will investigate on your statement about  interactive input. Tahnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use scanf! This is an age old discussion that use of scanf requires care and is dangerous. [Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).

Instead use [fgets()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm).

Check this answer [How to read from stdin with fgets()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919009/how-to-read-from-stdin-with-fgets) or this 
[Not able to input a string with spaces in a loop in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45038176/not-able-to-input-a-string-with-spaces-in-a-loop-in-c/45038767?noredirect=1#comment77052162_45038767)

But if you still insist on using scanf(), this may be useful:

```
 while(i<nbEleves){
        printf("Nom? ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]",array[i].Nom);// remove the \n and notice the space before %[^\n]
        printf("La note? ");
        scanf("%d", &array[i].Note);
        total = total + array[i].Note;
        i++;
}
```

Also I suggest that you must free the memory you allocated using free() in order to prevent memory leaks.

```
free(array);
```

Comment: I am not there yet in my courses, so maybe I am asking someting obvious but, which stream is the cmd? Because all I found is about files, even when the function is about streams. Is it STDIN? So basically I should get a  `fgets (array[i].Nom, 100, STDIN)` ?

Comment: @Zaphod yes you can say that console is stdin(Standard Input) in general. Its okay to ask obvious questions, have to learn this way or the other :) You can use fgets to get input from a file stream too. For standard console input you must use stdin. You want me on how to use fgets I can show you an example if you want?

Comment: Tahnks. I indeed would like an example with fgets in my situation. I already had the code with scanf with the comments on my ask, but I would love to get a good way of doing it with fgets.

Comment: @Zaphod Check this out: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMmtYNUM0dVFUWkE Just hit compile and then execute

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `\n` from `scanf("%s\n", array[i].Nom);` and `scanf("%d\n", &array[i].Note);` or press `CTRL + D` after you inserted the value.