# Taking strings as a 2-D char array

Tags: c, string, loops, multidimensional-array, char

I want a code such that I enter some strings one-by-one (by pressing enter) and display it.
for example;

Input

```
abc
def
```

Output

```
abc    
def
```

also I want this input to be in a array so that I can select any character

from the array whenever I want. For example: s[1][1] gives 'e'.

I have writen a code for this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, m;

    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    char a[n][m];

    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%s", a[i]);


    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s", a[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

But for this code my input/output goes like this:

Input

```
ab
cd
```

Output

```
abcd
cd
```

Can anyone tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: The input you have shown in question is missing the input value of `n` and `m`. Show the input value you are giving to `n` and `m`.

Comment: While with gcc and `c99+` there is no problem with the *Variable Length Array of Arrays* `char a[n][m];`, note that not all compilers support them. After you have the basics handled, look at declaring/allocating a number of pointers (e.g. `char **a = malloc (n * sizeof *a);`), reading with a sufficiently large buffer (e.g. `char buf[1024] = ""; scanf("%s", buf);` (checking return)) and then allocating storage for each string (e.g. `a[0] = malloc (strlen (buf) + 1); strcpy (a[0], buf);`). This provides allocated storage for your strings, while providing access with string indexes, `a[1][1]`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are working with a 2D array of `char`:

```
char a[n][m];
```

but keep in mind the value for the 2nd index should be 1 character longer than the length of the string you wish it to allow room for the `\0` byte.  (all C strings must be null terminated)

This means `char a[n][m];` can contain up to `n` strings, each string with maximum length of `m-1` bytes.

```
char exampleStr[] = {"char count"}; //for example contains 11 characters (not 10)

|c|h|a|r| |c|o|u|n|t|\0|  //note nul char is appended
```

Another common problem when reading user input in a loop  is failure to remove any unwanted newlines, which can cause the loop to behave poorly.  Following is an example of how to read a user specified number of strings ( using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` ), each with a user specified length: (also removing unwanted newlines ( `\n` ) in the process)

For readability, the following example replaces `n` & `m` with `lines` & `maxLen`.

```
int main(void)
{
    int lines, maxLen, i=0;

    printf("Enter number of lines:");
    scanf(" %d", &lines);
    printf("Enter maxLen line length:");
    scanf(" %d", &maxLen);

    char line[lines][maxLen+2]; //+2 to allow for trailing newline and null

    fgets(line[i], maxLen, stdin);//consume anything left in stdout
    printf("Enter up to %d characters and hit return:\n%d) ", maxLen, i+1);
    for(i=0;i<(lines);i++)
    {
        fgets(line[i], maxLen, stdin);
        line[i][strcspn(line[i], "\n")] = 0; // clear newline
        printf("Enter up to %d characters and hit return:\n%d) ", maxLen, i+1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The extra `line[i][strcspn(line[i], "\n")] = 0` is useless as the `%s` conversion format reads words, not lines. It would be useful if you were reading lines with `fgets()` (a safer approach indeed) but you would need to define line as `char line[lines][maxLen+2];` to allow for both the trailing newline and the null terminator.

Comment: @chqrlie - Good feedback.  Edited suggestions in.

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown the input value of `n` and `m` in the question. But from the input and output string shown, it seems that `char` array `a[i]` does not have the enough space for terminating null-character `\0`. When you give format specifier `%s`, `scanf()` automatically adds a terminating null character at the end of the stored sequence. I tried your code with input `2` for both `n` and `m` and I am getting the output as you are getting:

```
$ ./a.out
2 2
ab
cd
abcd
cd
```

Give the value `4` to `m` and the output is:

```
2 4
ab
cd
ab
cd
```

When using `scanf()` for string input, it is good to add check for max character modifier that is `1` less than the length of the input buffer. So, if the size of input buffer is `4` then you can do

```
scanf("%3s",a[i]);
```

With this, the `scanf()` will read not more than `3` characters in `a[i]` and will add `\0` at the fourth location of `a[i]`. Beware with this, it does not discard the remaining input from input stream and they will be consumed by consecutive `scanf()` call.

If you want to drop the extra input which wasn't consumed by scanf, one way of doing it is to read and discard the extra input using a loop, like this:

```
int c;
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    /* discard the character */;
```

You can add it after `scanf()` reads data from input stream, like this:

```
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        scanf("%3s", a[i]);  // assuming the size of a[i] is 4
        int c;
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)  // <=== This loop read the extra input characters and discard them
            /* discard the character */;
    }
```

This will work fine for the input that does not contain any whitespace characters. If your input contain any whitespace character, it may not behave as expected. Hence, I would suggest you to read about `fgets()` which gives you better control for string input.

Check this: [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)
and this: [How to read from stdin with fgets()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919009/how-to-read-from-stdin-with-fgets)

Answer (score 0):

All strings in C must be terminated with the null character `\0`, print knows this and prints all character UP TO that sign. You should make all of your strings 1 character longer than the words you plan to fit in them and fill them with 0 (0 is the integer value of `\0`) in the start to avoid this problem.

Comment: If I try doing that my output of other strings stops as well
for example:
Input
abc
def
If I make s[3]='\0';
output
abc

..

Comment: What is s[3], you mean a[i][3], which should be `a[i][m-1]` in general?

Comment: scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
        char a[n][m];

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);

In the scanf, when I used a gap before %c, my code worked fine. Without the gap, it doesn't work. why?

Comment: @AyazSImran - the gap in `" %c"` consumes the newline character, which can poor loop behavior.  There are other methods to do this as well.  (see above)