# Why edited string added after another string

Tags: c, string

I was trying to get input from user but when i set a variable for it it also adds it self to another variable

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("Enter String: ");
    char a[10];
    scanf("%s", a);

    char t[8] = "00:00:00";
    printf("%s\n", t);

}
```

Terminal

```
enter string: asd
00:00:00asd
```

Comment: Arguably better still would be to let the compiler work out the size automatically: `char t[] = "00:00:00";`

Answer (score 1):

Because `"00:00:00"` needs 9 space (including the terminating `'\0'` ) and you only give it 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer stores the variables on the stack. All variables are added to stack but the stack grows to the lowest addresses.

Until the scanf, the stack lookes like:

Variable a:

| Address Offset | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | ?? |
| -6 | 0 |
| -7 | 'd' |
| -8 | 's' |
| -9 | 'a' |

The scanf function reads in a line and terminates it with a '0' character which equals 0. That's why we have a 0 in cell -6 The upper addresses are not used because your input line has only three characters and the terminating 0.

Now comes the variable t:

| Address Offset | Value |
| --- | --- |
| -10 | '0' |
| -11 | '0' |
| -12 | ':' |
| -13 | '0' |
| -14 | '0' |
| ... |  |

As you can see, we get a contigous block of memory starting from -17 to -6 with the the string "00:00:00asd" and a terminating 0.

This block is being printed 00:00:00asd. This issue is called buffer overflow or especially string overflow.

You can fix it with this modified code but you will have similiar issues if you enter a line during during scanf that is longer than 9 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    printf("Enter String: ");
    char a[10];
    scanf("%s", a);

    char t[9] = "00:00:00";
    printf("%s\n", t);

}
```

```
florian@florian-desktop:~$ ./a.out 
Enter String: asdfasdfasd
00:00:00
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
```

Instead you could use fgets: [How to read from stdin with fgets()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919009/how-to-read-from-stdin-with-fgets) (Steve Emmersons answer)